# Find filenames containing a string defined as a variable

Tags: python, glob

I have sets of multiple files per patient that all contain a patient ID and a string identifying the type of file in the name, and I'm trying to loop over the patients and perform some steps on the different files inside the loop, so essentially the code should do something like "for patient 1, this is the patient ID, now in subdirectory X find the files containing this ID and the string test_A/test_B/test_C in their name". The problem is that I don't know how to identify files that contain the patient ID, everything I tried with wildcards would take the variable "patient_ID" as a literal string. The alternative that works is nested loops where I search for filenames containing the ID. I assume this is not very efficient and would appreciate any tips!

There is one directory per test which contains files for all patients:

test_A/

├─ pat_1_test_A_343980235

├─ pat_2_test_A_343958030

├─ pat_3_test_A_4539830

test_B/

├─ pat_1_test_B_934292

├─ pat_2_test_B_2495345

├─ pat_3_test_B_2948298

...

What I have is:

```
for file_A in glob.glob(base_dir + 'test_A'):
        id = file_A.split('pat-')[-1].split('_test')[0]
        for file_B in glob.glob(base_dir + 'test_B'):
            if id in file_B:
                ... # perform steps with file_A and file_B
```

...and this is getting increasingly complicated as I need not just two different files, but 4 or 5, resulting in nested loops.

Comment: If you need to glob e.g. `pat_1_test_*` and you have the patient id (assuming it's `1`) in the variable `id`, you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) such as `f"pat_{id}_test_*"`

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the patient id in the filename `pat_1_test_A_343980235` and what you want from it.

Comment: @etuardu Thank you! This also works and is actually enough for my use case so I implemented your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could isolate the patient IDs and store them in a dictionary according to their folder:

```
from pathlib import Path

directories = ['test_A', 'test_B']
id_by_dir = dict()
all_patient_files = list()
for directory in directories:
    # retrieve Path obj of files in each dir
    id_by_dir[directory] = list()
    patient_files = Path(directory).glob('*')
    for file in patient_files:
        # file is a Path object; cast to str
        split_by_slash = str(file).split('/')
        all_patient_files.append(str(file))
        folder = split_by_slash[0]
        patient_file = split_by_slash[1]
        fn_comps = patient_file.split('_')
        pid = fn_comps[-1]
        id_by_dir[directory].append(pid)

print(id_by_dir)
```

this will give you:

```
{'test_A': ['343958030', '343980235', '4539830'], 'test_B': ['2495345', '2948298', '934292']}
```

and then create a list of IDs in both directories:

```
ids_in_both = [pid for pid in id_by_dir['test_A'] if pid in id_by_dir['test_B']]
print(ids_in_both) # ['123456']
```

I added the file 'pat_4_test_A_123456' and 'pat_4_test_B_123456' to my test_A and test_B directories, respectively. So,

```
id_files = dict()
for pid in ids_in_both:
    files = [file for file in all_patient_files if file.endswith(pid)]
    id_files[pid] = files
print(id_files)  # {'123456': ['test_A/pat_4_test_A_123456', 'test_B/pat_4_test_B_123456']}
for pid in id_files:
    for path in id_files[pid]:
        print(Path(path))
        print(Path(path).stem)
```

which prints:

```
test_A/pat_4_test_A_123456
pat_4_test_A_123456
test_B/pat_4_test_B_123456
pat_4_test_B_123456
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and was very helpful with all the details!